# What is MTK NLP Service?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sony-xperia, location-services

I have a Sony XPERIA M5 Dual (E5663) with stock Android 6.0. Recently I found that my GPS is activated without any app running. I checked Locations in the settings and found an app called MTK NLP Service has been requesting GPS location. I can't seem to remove it. What is that app and why does it need GPS?

Comment: MTK=MediaTek that is the chip manufacturer of at least one chip in your Smartphone. Most likely it is the central service handling location requests on your system.

Comment: NLP - Network Location Provider.